# How to configure Apache to run on multiple network interfaces?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a Linux system that has two Ethernet ports, one GPRS modem interface and Wifi.  How can I configure Apache to run on all or a subset of those interfaces?  Wifi & GPRS modem IP addresses will prob. be dynamic, ethernet addresses fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Apache Listen directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html) handles that.

All interfaces:

```
Listen 80
```

Specific IP only:

```
Listen 192.0.2.1:80
```

Comment: How could I specify it to listen say only on the Wifi interface, where the address is assigned by DHCP?  Is there any way to specify an inteface, e.g. "wlan0"?

Comment: Those addresses are usually more static than you'd think.  At least, as long as your host is perpetually online.  In the worst case, write some shell script to check the output of ifconfig/ip for the interface you want and then stuff that into your apache config and restart.

Comment: Another idea: listen on all and firewall ones you don't want connections on.

Answer (score 3):

By default apache will listen on all available interfaces

```
# cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep ^Listen
Listen 80
```

So there is no need in any specific configuration at all